# Cordova browser opens a different Chrome?

Tags: cordova, google-chrome

When I use `cordova run browser` or alternatively `cordova run browser --target=chrome` the process starts a new Chrome window with a different version Chrome than my default.

<s>On my system I have my regular installation (currently at v58), a Chrome Canary installation (currently at v61) and Cordova opens a new Chrome with v59.</s>
(This weird reporting was probably due to a pending install on my regular Chrome, both regular Chrome and Cordova's opened Chrome are v59)

Why does Cordova not start in a new tab, or why can't I even drag the newly opened window into a tab of my already open regular Chrome?

Comment: Note that with `--target=opera` for example the app will start into a new tab of an already open Opera. This is the behaviour I'd like for Chrome or the default without the `--target` options.

Comment: It probably launchs a new window because it launch it with `--disable-web-security` flag

Comment: Is there a way to disable that flag?

Comment: I've checked and it was removed long time ago https://github.com/apache/cordova-browser/pull/9. But in this comment, it says that Chrome needs to be launched in a new window, not sure why https://github.com/apache/cordova-serve/blob/master/src/browser.js#L50

Comment: I've seen that comment in the code, but removing it doesn't change a) that it opens in a new window and b) that that new window doesn't have me logged in as usually in chrome.

Comment: @kontur Hi Kontur, its "--user-data-dir" param that we pass along with chrome.exe results in the behavior of opening a chrome instance in new window. This feature is incorporated so that user specific data can be kept separately for testing. This is same reason why you are not able to even drag drop the newly opened window into an already opened instance of chrome. Basically its done to maintain the integrity of individual instances. Hope it helps

Comment: @kontur do keep us posted on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `--user-data-dir` param that we pass along with chrome.exe, results in the behavior of opening a chrome instance in new window. This feature is incorporated so that user specific data can be kept separately for testing.

This is same reason why you are not able to even drag drop the newly opened window into an already opened instance of chrome. Basically its done to maintain the integrity of individual instances.

The tweak to stop opening new instance of chrome instance(though not recommended unless its really a requirement) is to edit the `browser.js` file under `/Projectroot/platforms/browser/cordova/node_modules/cordova_serve/src` folder as you have mentioned in your answer and stop passing the `--user-data-dir` parameter. Hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: I have the opposite problem: I recently upgraded Cordova and now "cordova run browser" opens apps in a new tab in my existing Chrome instance instead of in an entirely new instance as it used to. I prefer the previous behavior but I can't see how to force it -- looking at browser.js, --user-data-dir seems to be defined. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @williamwhyte is it related to chrome settings by any chance? Did u tried it manually by passing user data dir in chrome.exe properties and try opening it manually??

Comment: On a Mac, I ran
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome  --args --user-data-dir ~/tmp.

I got the error "[28294:37891:1016/131241.702920:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process." but that seems to be unrelated. 

Chrome started with a new tab in an existing window and with me logged in, rather than as a separate process and with no user logged in.

So it looks like this is a change in Chrome rather than in Cordova. Hope the Cordova team will be able to work out the change and modify the CLI appropriately.

Comment: @williamwhyte quiet possible. But can't comment on this as I have not tried this on Mac ever

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Gandhi 's comments I found that switching the `var chromeArgs` to an empty string in `/Projectroot/platforms/browser/cordova/node_modules/cordova_serve/src/browserjs` on line 82 achieves the desired result of opening the preview in my default Chrome with logged in user.

This seems a somewhat hacky approach, so I am glad for any more sophisticated solutions on how to reliably switch this from the default behaviour.

Comment: as far as i know, thats the possible tweak you could do as the "run browser" command is intended to work with a specific user data directory

Comment: have posted the consolidated answer.Accept if it was useful.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer as it could be the best possible solution as far as i know and bounty seems to be running out. Thanks in advance

Comment: I upvoted your answer and it will be awarded the bounty when the timer runs out since it is the best answer so far. I didn't mark it as solved or award the bounty manually because I'd hope there would be a better, more automated way even. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: the bounty wont be awarded unless the answer is accepted. Also it requires a minimum of 2 or more up votes to get awarded with just half of the total bounty. as mentioned earlier, what you are trying to achieve is itself a tweak so there wont be any automated or better way to it as its not intended to work this way.

Comment: Roger, I'll check back before the bounty expires